# Flat JSON result from FOR JSON on SQL Server with joined query

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a query that I need to send to SQL Server and use `FOR JSON` to get the result back as JSON. This query can include one or more JOINs.

The problem is that I want the result back as a simple flat json with each column as a column, but FOR `JSON AUTO` automatically nests it (Duh) and `FOR JSON PATH` is not appropriate because it use the dot-syntax but I want it to completely ignore any of that.

Of course, this could be done on the application server quite easily but I would highly prefer to do this in the database.

Query:

```
SELECT
    [Product].[ProductName] AS [Product.ProductName], 
    [Category].[CategoryName] AS [Category.CategoryName], 
    [Supplier].[CompanyName] AS [Supplier.CompanyName] 
FROM
    [Products] AS [Product] 
    INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [Category] ON [Category].[CategoryID] = [Product].[CategoryID] 
    LEFT JOIN [Suppliers] AS [Supplier] ON [Supplier].[SupplierID] = [Product].[SupplierID] 
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Result (For 1):

```
[
    {
        "Product.ProductName":"Test prod",
        "Category":[
            {
                "Category.CategoryName":"Condiments!!!",
                "Supplier":[
                    {
                        "Supplier.CompanyName":"Exotic Liquids"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
[
    {
        "Product.ProductName":"Test Prod",
        "Category.CategoryName":"Condiments!!!",
        "Supplier.CompanyName":"Exotic Liquids"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please show your attempts, some sample data and your query and what the output is and include your desired output

Comment: @Tanner Added samples

Comment: @Blanen why don't you use `JSON PATH`? What is the result, are there any errors? The format genearated by `JSON AUTO` is *very* reasonable - JSON means nested, not flat. If you didn't include the table name in the column name you'd get a very common JSON response. The format you want is unconventional on the other hand. The JSON way is to have a `Product` object with a `ProductName` property, not something with `Product.ProductName`.

Comment: BTW not my downvote. Without table creation and population queries though, I can't even try what you posted. I'd have to try and rebuild the tables and add the data just to test the queries.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's supposed to represent a table row, not an actual object of any kind. The names are supposed to be arbitrairy. I want to send this to the frontend to display as a table but also have the ability to export this as CSV/ Excel/ Etc. It would obviously be easiest if I don't have to manually flatten the results on every action on my application server or on the browser.

This is compatible with the Northwind database IIRC

Comment: For you, not for anyone else. `AUTO` means `auto` - something meaningful for everyone. It's not a random format either, that's similar to what `FOR XML AUTO` produces. I'd bet other databases produce similar formats. Why don't you use `FOR JSON PATH` if you want to specify your own form?

Comment: Or why don't you *make* the results flat? If you queried eg a view, nested query or CTE I'd bet the results of `FOR JSON AUTO` would appear flat, as if you queried a single table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That only makes it ignore the part in the names I've given the columns before the `.`, but the names are supposed to be arbitrary, they can include any unicode character, even emoji's for all I care and all the `.` they want. 

`AUTO` is prefered to `PATH` in this situation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for referring to CTE, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2):

Working solution:

```
WITH test_CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Product].[ProductName] AS [Product.ProductName],
        [Category].[CategoryName] AS [Category.CategoryName],
        [Supplier].[CompanyName] AS [Supplier.CompanyName] 
    FROM 
        [Products] AS [Product] 
        INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [Category] ON [Category].[CategoryID] = [Product].[CategoryID] 
        LEFT JOIN [Suppliers] AS [Supplier] ON [Supplier].[SupplierID] = [Product].[SupplierID]
)
SELECT * FROM test_CTE FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it only in 1 to 1 relationship:

```
SELECT
    [Product].[ProductName] AS [Product.ProductName], 
    (SELECT [Category].[CategoryName] FROM [Categories] WHERE [Category].[CategoryID] = [Product].[CategoryID]) AS [Category.CategoryName], 
    (SELECT [Supplier].[CompanyName] FROM [Suppliers] WHERE [Supplier].[SupplierID] = [Product].[SupplierID]) AS [Supplier.CompanyName] 
FROM
    [Products] AS [Product] 
FOR JSON AUTO
```